# Flutter: setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build for a wrapper widget & and global variables widget

Tags: android, flutter, dart

From other answers on this topic, it seems that there might be something wrong with how I call a function that is making a snackbar or a dialog box appear before a build completes. The error is pointing to `notifyListeners()` in `globalsProvider.dart`. This is a function defined in `change_notifier.dart`.

In my app, `wrapper.dart` is a wrapper that watches the signed in state of the user and is above most other widgets. `globalsProvider.dart` is a file that holds globals variables.

**wrapper.dart:**

```
class Wrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  const Wrapper({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final globalsProvider = Provider.of<GlobalsProvider>(context);
    globalsProvider.userGlobals();

    final user = Provider.of<ModelUser?>(context);

    //return either Home or Authenticate widget
    if (user == null) {
      return Authenticate();
    } else {
      return Home();
    }
  }
}
```

**globalsProvider.dart:**

```
class GlobalsProvider extends ChangeNotifier {

  Future<void> userGlobals() async {
    final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    final currentUsersCollection = usersCollection();
    if (user != null) {
      currentUID = user.uid;
      final userData = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(currentUsersCollection).doc(currentUID).get();
      currentUsername = userData.data()?['username'] ?? '';
    }
    notifyListeners(); //ERROR IS HERE
  }
}
```

**notifyListeners:**

```
void notifyListeners() {
    assert(ChangeNotifier.debugAssertNotDisposed(this));
    if (_count == 0) {
      return;
    }

    // To make sure that listeners removed during this iteration are not called,
    // we set them to null, but we don't shrink the list right away.
    // By doing this, we can continue to iterate on our list until it reaches
    // the last listener added before the call to this method.

    // To allow potential listeners to recursively call notifyListener, we track
    // the number of times this method is called in _notificationCallStackDepth.
    // Once every recursive iteration is finished (i.e. when _notificationCallStackDepth == 0),
    // we can safely shrink our list so that it will only contain not null
    // listeners.

    _notificationCallStackDepth++;

    final int end = _count;
    for (int i = 0; i < end; i++) {
      try {
        _listeners[i]?.call();
      } catch (exception, stack) {
        FlutterError.reportError(FlutterErrorDetails(
          exception: exception,
          stack: stack,
          library: 'foundation library',
          context: ErrorDescription('while dispatching notifications for $runtimeType'),
          informationCollector: () => <DiagnosticsNode>[
            DiagnosticsProperty<ChangeNotifier>(
              'The $runtimeType sending notification was',
              this,
              style: DiagnosticsTreeStyle.errorProperty,
            ),
          ],
        ));
      }
    }

    _notificationCallStackDepth--;

    if (_notificationCallStackDepth == 0 && _reentrantlyRemovedListeners > 0) {
      // We really remove the listeners when all notifications are done.
      final int newLength = _count - _reentrantlyRemovedListeners;
      if (newLength * 2 <= _listeners.length) {
        // As in _removeAt, we only shrink the list when the real number of
        // listeners is half the length of our list.
        final List<VoidCallback?> newListeners = List<VoidCallback?>.filled(newLength, null);

        int newIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < _count; i++) {
          final VoidCallback? listener = _listeners[i];
          if (listener != null) {
            newListeners[newIndex++] = listener;
          }
        }

        _listeners = newListeners;
      } else {
        // Otherwise we put all the null references at the end.
        for (int i = 0; i < newLength; i += 1) {
          if (_listeners[i] == null) {
            // We swap this item with the next not null item.
            int swapIndex = i + 1;
            while(_listeners[swapIndex] == null) {
              swapIndex += 1;
            }
            _listeners[i] = _listeners[swapIndex];
            _listeners[swapIndex] = null;
          }
        }
      }

      _reentrantlyRemovedListeners = 0;
      _count = newLength;
    }
  }
```

Comment: i haven't try to run your code, is call `notifyListeners()` will not cause `Wrapper` rebuilt?

Comment: @Zhentao not sure, it's a function built in to Flutter. I've edited the question to show the definition of the function

Comment: Focus on where you call the userGlobals() function.  Since it is going to call notifyListeners and trigger a rebuild, you don't want to call it from a build function. Maybe the Wrapper class should be converted to a StatefullWidget and then call userGlobals from initState instead of from the build() method.

Comment: @JohnWeidner I tried converting to stful and calling from initState, but it gave this error: `Unhandled Exception: dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<_InheritedProviderScope<GlobalsProvider?>>() or dependOnInheritedElement() was called before _WrapperState.initState() completed.`

Answer (score 0):

This error comes when you use the variables or functions inside build body but they are not yet initialized or loaded properly. Most of the time this occurs when you call a Future type of function from provider in initState method without binding this, so while build widget is building, provider updates value so this error occurs.

**Solution:**
wrap your provider method inside **WidgetBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback** method like this

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
  loadData();
});
```

Place all your loading code inside loadData() function.